# when to use iso_Fortran_env ,selected_int_kind,real(8),or -fdefault-real-8 for writing or compiling fortran code?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I have this simple code which uses `DGEMM` routine for matrix multiplication

```
program check

  implicit none
  real(8),dimension(2,2)::A,B,C
  A(1,1)=4.5
  A(1,2)=4.5
  A(2,1)=4.5
  A(2,2)=4.5
  B(1,1)=2.5
  B(1,2)=2.5
  B(2,1)=2.5
  B(2,2)=2.5

  c=0.0

  call DGEMM('n','n',2,2,2,1.00,A,2,B,2,0.00,C,2)
  print *,C(1,1)    
  print *,C(1,2)  

  print *,C(2,1)    
  print *,C(2,2)
end program check
```

now when  i compile this code with command

```
gfortran -o check check.f90   -lblas
```

I get some random garbage values. But when I add

> -fdefault-real-8

to the compiling options I get correct values.

But since it is not a good way of variable declaration in Fortran. So I used the `iso_fortran_env` intrinsic module and added two lines to the code

```
use iso_fortran_env
real(kind=real32),dimension(2,2)::A,B,C
```

and compiled with

```
 gfortran -o check check.f90 -lblas
```

Again I got wrong output .
Where I'm  erring in this code?
I'm on 32bit linux and  using GCC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DGEMM`](http://www.math.utah.edu/software/lapack/lapack-blas/dgemm.html) expects `double precision` values for `ALPHA` and `BETA`.

Without further options, you are feeding single precision floats to LAPACK - hence the garbage. 
Using `-fdefault-real-8` you force every float specified to be double precision by default, and `DGEMM` is fed correctly.

In your case, the call should be:

```
call DGEMM('n','n',2,2,2,1.00_8,A,2,B,2,0.00_8,C,2)
```

which specifies the value for alpha to be `1` as a float of kind 8, and zero of kind 8 for beta.

If you want to perform the matrix-vector product in *single precision*, use [`SGEMM`](http://www.math.utah.edu/software/lapack/lapack-blas/sgemm.html).

Note that this is highly compiler-specific, you should consider using `REAL32`/`REAL64`  from the `ISO_Fortran_env` module instead (also for the declaration of `A`, `B`, and `C`).

Comment: Good catch, I missed the default real constants. Theoretically, double precision is still more certain when calling BLAS then real64, but  it wilk work in vast majority of cases.

Comment: @VladimirF I always compile BLAS/LAPACK with the same compiler I use for my Fortran code, and (hence?) have never experienced problems with using `REAL64`.

Comment: This does not guarantee everything. If the default real was 64 bits for some processor, than double is 128 bits and real64 will be equivalent to a single not to a double.

Comment: @VladimirF So, if on processor with default double as 128bits and we pass real64  to DEMM, will it result an error?